# Quit Indexed Stack in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have created a bottom navigation bar with an indexed stack. The problem is when I want to go to the first page in my app the bottom navigation bar is still there and when I go to the page where I create the bar, a new second bar is created. How can I destroy the navigation bar / indexed stack.

It is set up like this:

```
First page -> indexed stack -> the individual pages (Here is a button where it goes back to the first page).
```

Comment: Can you some code, how you implemented it?

Comment: I have no clue about what you are trying to say. Please include a piece of code with more info and images for better understanding the issues